# Get drive index using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, wmi, wmic

I'm currently playing with VirtualBox and one of the things that annoy me with it is that you have to do such a workaround to get it to boot from USB. So I'm thinking of automating this with a batch file.
But one of the problems that I run into is that the command needs the index number of the physical device that is your USB drive, not the drive letter.
The original instructions I found ask you to open the disk management app, look-up the drive number and add it to the command by hand. But I'm trying to make a batch file that will show the user the drive index number and the physical device's model tag in a list a bit like this

```
Drive Name
0     Hitachi HDS721050CLA660
1     Sony Storage Media USB Device
2     SanDisk SanDisk Ultra USB Device
```

I was originally thinking of using the fdisk -l function like in Linux but that won't work. So, I ended up using WMIC to get some information

```
wmic diskdrive list /format:list
```

but that only gives me a long list, not the only information I want.
Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the USB drive should be seen as Mediatype `Removable Media`

```
wmic diskdrive where "MediaType='Removable Media'" get index,model
```

Comment: That works very well... it's even cleaner than what I expected. Too bad there is so little good documentation on wmic...

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out!
And it was simpler than expected

```
wmic diskdrive get index,model
```

Enjoy!